# Can you use a "power of 2" gate in the BGW protocol

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

I am learning about the BGW Protocol and I understand that for a MUL gate, you need to follow the degree reduction protocol. I am wondering if it is possible to implement a single input and single output "SQUARE" gate that computes the square of the input?

I imagine some sort of degree reduction protocol would be involved but when I try using it in the same way as for the MUL gate, it does not seem to be working. Does anyone know if implementing such a gate is possible for the BGW protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it shouldn't work. If you ran the multiplication protocol using the same polynomial for both inputs, doesn't that work? Each party would square its share and then run degree reduction.